# Tornado Session in Redis

Tags: session, redis, tornado

I am writing a lightweight Tornado based comet server.
I would like to store the "self" object in redis to maintain the state..
Will this work?

For a start, i cant even serialize self to be stored in Redis..

This is the error

```
File "sessionsupport.py", line 27, in get
    this = cPickle.dumps(self,1)
  File "/home/test/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 70, in _reduce_ex
    raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
TypeError: can't pickle instancemethod objects
```

any suggestions on how i would do this?

Comment: The "self" object from what context? A RequestHandler instance?

Answer (score 2):

I'm unsure of if the `self` object refers to an instance of `RequestHandler`, or maybe some type of `Session` instance you have. Whichever it is, you're probably going to want to convert your object to a dict before pickling and saving to redis. At least, that's what I do with MongoDB. My Tornado sessions:

- Are `dict`s that contain any data I want to persist throughout the users' sessions
- Are assigned an ID which is:

  - Saved along with the dict in my datastore (redis or MongoDB)
  - Stored in a user's cookie

Comment: Yes it refers to the RequestHandler that points at a particular client..
How do you do this from Tornado?